# Align jquery dialog popup to the center of screen in IE and Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, popup, jquery-dialog

There is my code so far. The issue is that the popup seems  to be working perfect in Chrome but in Firefox it sticks to the top of the window after entering and in IE the popup does not even appear.

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="My Dialog Title" style="display:none">
    <p>This is My Dialog box Description/Content</p>   

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {    
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            show: {
            effect: 'drop',
            direction : 'up',
            distance: 1000,
            duration: 2000,
            },
        });
      });
    }, 2000)
});


</script>

<style>
.ui-dialog-titlebar {display:none;}
#other_content {width:200px; height:200px;background-color:grey;}
#dialog_content{display:none;}
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the popup to behave in the same manner as it is in Chrome with all the browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/fakhruddin/x39Rr/14/

[Web Page Link](http://butterflyhomes.in/investonline/popup)

Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add:

```
<body style="height:100%">
```

Comment: yes it resolved for firefox but for IE Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 05:40:29 UTC


Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 29
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: http://butterflyhomes.in/investonline/popup

Comment: Remove commas in lines: "duration: 2000" and next one. But in Ie8 this function doesn't work as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple! Add to the begin of file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```